# PhantomJS - pause/resume javascript execution

Tags: javascript, jquery, webkit, jquery-animate, phantomjs

I have a PhantomJS script that I'm trying to use in order to essentially generate a video of a particular website.

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.viewportSize = {
    width: 1280,
    height: 720
};
page.open('http://my-awesome-site.whatever', function() {
    var fps = 30;
    var seconds = 10;
    var elapsed = 0;
    var current = 0;

    takeScreenShot();

    function takeScreenShot() {
        if (elapsed < seconds * 1000) {
            page.render('screenshot_' + (current++) + '.png');
            elapsed += 1000 / fps;
            setTimeout(takeScreenShot, 1000 / fps);
        }
        else {
            phantom.exit();
        }
    }
});
```

The above script will attempt to take 30 screenshots per second for 10 seconds, which I then combine into an mp4 using ffmpeg.

The problem is that the page.render() function is not instantaneous, and does not halt the scripts running on the page. So when I'm pointing at a page using jQuery animations, which I believe rely on setTimeout, those timeouts continue to run while each screenshot is processed. As a result, the outputted video appears greatly sped up.

Is there a way through PhantomJS to pause script execution? What I'm hoping for is to do something like:

```
page.pause();
page.render('screenshot_' + (current++) + '.png');
page.resume();
```

But sadly, I don't see anything like that in their api docs.

Answer (score 1):

You could set `page.settings.javascriptEnabled=false` if the page looks don't depend on JS too much.
Be aware that you need to define the settings before the first call as they are evaluated only once eg :

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.settings = {
    javascriptEnabled=false
}
```

See : http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/property/settings.html

If it doesn't fit your need, you need to dig into the code of the page to find a way to stop the animations (use your browser's console). Once you know what you need to do, just evaluate the command in Phantom.

```
page.open('http://my-awesome-site.whatever', function() {
  var stopScripts = page.evaluate(function() {
     // do whatever you need to stop execution
     return true;
  });
  // ... take your screenshots
});
```

Comment: Disabling javascript won't work because I need to resume execution between screenshots. Your second suggestion might work, I could put some sort of global pause/resume functions on the page, but it would be a lot to add at this point. I was hoping there would be an easier way.